# creating web api and calling asynchronous

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I am creating web api. I want to call in bot messenger framework.

In web api controller i have method :

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString());
            return response;
        }
```

In the bot framework i have this code :

```
 public static async Task<List<EventModel>> Response(string uri)
        {
            //string escapeString = Uri.EscapeDataString(phrase);
            string returnValue = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var message = await client.GetAsync(uri);
                    if (message.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var jsonResponse = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        jsonResponse = jsonResponse.TrimStart('\"');
                        jsonResponse = jsonResponse.TrimEnd('\"');
                        jsonResponse = jsonResponse.Replace("\\", "");
                        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EventModel>>(jsonResponse);
                        return data;
                    }
                    else return null;

                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

the problem : `client.GetAsync(uri)` never ends.

Some help ?

Comment: how are you sure it **never ends**?

Comment: How do you invoke *Response*?

Comment: Have you verified using breakpoints in debug where the call goes? I would trace down through with the debugger and see where things go wrong.

Comment: Hey guys. I found out what the problem was. Methods in web api were async. Changed them to sync and now everything works fine.